# reactjs - unit testing with enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jsdom

I am oretty new to react and am trying to unit test the following piece of code that I have in my react component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

const styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];

const keyframes =
  `@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
  }`;

styleSheet.insertRule(keyframes, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
const style = {
  animation: 'pulse 5.5s infinite ease-in-out'
};

class someclass extends Component {

  render() {
    return (    
      <svg style={style}>

      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default someclass;
```

This is my test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, mount, render} from 'enzyme'
import {expect} from 'chai'
import someclassfrom '.../src/components/someclass';

describe('someclass', () => {
  it('should have the main svg', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<someclass/>);
    expect(wrapper.find('svg')).to.have.length(1);

  })
})
```

but I keep on getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

How I can mock the same? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried simplifying stuff down and commenting out the style handling code before the definition of the component?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to check the length I do something like this:

```
expect(wrapper.find('svg').length).to.equal(1);
```

Also, be sure to write your import as:

```
import someclass from '.../src/components/someclass';
```

Because yours was:

```
import someclassfrom '.../src/components/someclass';
```

Notice there was not a space in between the component name and the from.

I hope this helps you.

Edit: I forgot to mention, use uppercase for your component name, React uses it to know it is a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

@pj013 for unit testing of your component. you can use Jest + Enzyme combination:

```
expect(wrapper.find('svg').length).toEqual(1);
```

or

```
expect(wrapper.find('svg').length).toBe(1);
```

Comment: this is wrong, `toEqual` and `toBe` are different. `toBe` would return `false` for two different instances of objects that have equal value, whereas `toEqual` would return true. Please do not confuse other users: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/using-matchers.html